# Отправить почту через .РФ домен

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Для рассылки почты использовал достаточно простой метод отправки.

```
public bool SendEmail(string UserName, string UserPassword, string emailTo, string subject, string body, bool isBodyHtml)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(emailTo))
        {
            return false;
        }
        using (System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtpClient = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient(SERVERSMTP, PORTNOSMTP))
        {

            smtpClient.EnableSsl = false;
            smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;                
            smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserName, UserPassword);
            using (MailMessage message = new MailMessage())
            {
                message.From = new MailAddress(UserName);
                message.Subject = subject == null ? "" : subject;                    
                message.Body = body == null ? "" : body;                    
                message.IsBodyHtml = isBodyHtml;
                message.To.Add(new MailAddress(emailTo));
                try
                {
                    smtpClient.Send(message);
                    return true;
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    //string s1 = exception.Message + "\n" + exception.InnerException + "\n" + exception.Data;
                    throw new FaultException(exception.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Всё отлично работает. Но необходимо отправлять почту с .рф домена и тут возникла проблема. Не возможно отправить, выдает ошибку

```
System.Net.WebException: Невозможно разрешить удаленное имя "мойсайт.рф"
```

пробовал добавить в код

```
 smtpClient.DeliveryFormat = SmtpDeliveryFormat.International;
```

тоже не помогло, как быть? где это разрешается? Читал про:

```
<uri>
<idn enabled="All"/>
<iriParsing enabled="true"/>
```

Но не могу понять как это в моём случае использовать?

Comment: Пробовали перевести доменное имя в [punycode](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode), т.е. «xn--80arbjktj.xn--p1ai» вместо «мойсайт.рф»?

Comment: пробовал, но не получается

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно сконвертировать домен в Punycode.

```
using System.Globalization;

            string unicode = @"россия.рф";
            IdnMapping mapping = new IdnMapping();
            string ascii = mapping.GetAscii(unicode);
            Console.WriteLine(ascii);
            string convertedBackToUnicode = mapping.GetUnicode(ascii);
            Console.WriteLine(convertedBackToUnicode);
```

Comment: Попробовал по вашему методу, стал ответ таким: Неправильная последовательность команд. Отклик сервера: This mail server requires authentication when attempting to send to a non-local e-mail address. Please check your mail client settings or contact your administrator to verify that the domain or address is defined for this server.

System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal

Comment: @DenisIvanov В `Username` есть домен? Его Вы аналогичным образом преобразовали?

Comment: Аааа, точно. Домен есть,поспешил, сори.

Comment: Большое спасибо!)